# My class interferes with library class

Tags: c++, class

I am currently programming on a 3d visualization program so I wrote my own Vector3 class to have some convenient vector operations. That worked fine until I needed to load some Meshes which I used an external library for that has its own Vector3 class. Now the compiler can't tell them apart and I can not change both because they are too heavily included in the code.
Has anyone an idea how I can separate them for the compiler?

I thought about creating a namespace around the inclusion of the loader but got errors in the libraries implementation.

Any Ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Unfortunately my own project as well as the library have no own namespace.

**(Solved)**
Ok I solved this by removing the library and refactoring my code automatically with eclipse. But if it would not be able to do this how could I solve this problem in C++ independent from the IDE? -> Not marked as answered

Comment: Namespaces are the solution here.  If you are getting compiler/linker errors, then you will need to edit your question to include some representative code, and then we can help you fix them.

Comment: Ehm. I'm pretty sure that library has its `Vector3` class in its own namespace.. if not, it's bad anyways. Are you using a `using namespace XXX;` for that library anywhere?

Comment: @Xeo: and one would hope the OP had put his own classes in a namespace...

Comment: Neither me nor the creator of the library used own namespaces. It is simply caused by the fact, that it is only prototyped so we never expected to have this interference because it was not thought to be given away. Anyways now I know about the problem and can avoid it in further work.

Comment: @Nobody - You can't just put the headers in a namespace, because the linker will not find the functions if they are not actually there.

Comment: Don't write "solved" in questions. If you found your solution, write an answer and accept it.

Comment: I did not want it marked answered because it wasn't in my opinion. Hence the short explanation and the paranthesis around solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> EDIT Unfortunately my own project as well as the library have no own namespace.

The solution is obvious. Put your project in a namespace. And refer to the Vector3 in the library with ::Vector3, if it truly does not have any namespace.

Comment: I dont use the Vector3 from the library myself. Only the library does. I consider adding the namespace afterwards as very tedious but probably it is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Use your project namespace before the classname you have created, and its builtin class.
like:

MyProject::Vector3D

xxx::Vector3D

where 'xxx' is the namespace in which builtin Vector3D class is in.

Comment: The scope operator in C++ is `::`, not `.`.